# Spacy dependency parsing: specify a token that has no dependency

Tags: python, spacy

How do you specify a token in the dependency parser that has no "dep" attributes? The token is the root token of the sentence.

In this example, I am trying to capture all run-on sentences that just have a noun phrase. So the approach would mean that a noun is the root of the sentence.

Is it possible to do this in the dependency parser? I know you can iterate linearly over the tokens and check for `token.root`.

[image]

My attempt:

```py
    {"RIGHT_ID": "noun", "RIGHT_ATTRS": {
        "POS": {"IN": ["PROPN", "NOUN"]}, 
        "DEP": {"NOT_IN": ["nsubj", "dobj", "compound"]}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check `token.dep_`, you'll see that the root token of a sentence has the dependency relation `ROOT`. You should just be able to specify that.